# Why am I getting different learning curve for SVC in using sklearn and sklearnex

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, svm

Now I'm using SVM.SVC to train the data.Due to the long execution time for using sklearn,I try to implement the sklearnex.After using same datas and parameters below, I get two different learning curves.Wondering if anyone run into the same issue,if so, how to due with it or where't the problem.

parameters:

- kernel = 'rbf'
- C = 1
- gamma = 1e-2
- max_iter = 3000
- random_state = 42
- tol =1e-3
- probability=True
- cache_size =500

packages version:

- scikit-learn - 1.1.1
- scikit-learn-intelex - 2023.2.1

learning curves:

- [By sklearn,with five fold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLmQS.png)
- [By sklearnex,with five fold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMo8E.png)

I have already visit the issue page on git,but find out nothing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have already got the responsed on git, who in need could check out here:https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex/issues/1390

Answer (score 1):

I ran a somewhat similar experiment, and got consistent results between sklearn/sklearnex:

[image]

I was using `SVR` with 5-fold CV and a similarly-sized dataset to yours. I ran it under sklearn 1.3.0. and sklearnex 2023.2.1. If you are able to run it under the newer sklearn, could be worth trying.